# Semantic ui List: Enable scrolling bar

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I have a semantic ui list which contains so many items that it is longer than the window. I want to have a scrolling bar only for the list itself, however, the browser displays a scrolling bar for the complete website.

Should I put the list in a container div and set its height=100% or what is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Yes, you could put it in a container div and set the div's height to something small (or 100%, whichever you prefer) and add overflow:auto for scrolling.

Comment: 100% does not work, the browser still shows a scrollbar for the complete website. However, if I set a px value it works. Is there a way to do this dynamically? It does not seem to be very "clean code" to hardcode a px value. I'd assume there is something in CSS to achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following css to you `ui list` div:

```
height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
```

To make this work, you have to make sure the div **containing** you list div has some fixed height. In the comment you mentioned that setting 100% doesn't work, this can happen if one of "ancestor" divs does not have fixed height.

Comment: I don't this works.
<div style="height:300px;"><table class="ui celled table" style="height:100%; overflow: scroll;">....</table></div>